# Grouping using AWK | COL1 and COL3

Tags: awk

I was trying to group col1 based on smallest value on col3, but was unable to do so.

```
Input:
rs3813193   ENSG00000215914 636821
rs3813193   ENSG00000215790 669121
rs3813193   ENSG00000078808 153810
rs3813193   ENSG00000142609 890192
rs3813193   ENSG00000160075 478552
rs3813193   ENSG00000188290 63024
rs3813193   ENSG00000169885 852139
rs3813193   ENSG00000160072 408663
rs3813193   ENSG00000162576 289570
```

```
Desired output:
rs3813193   ENSG00000188290 63024
```

```
My code:
awk '$3<min[$1]{min[$1]=$3; row[$1]=$0} END{for (i in row) print row[i]}'
```

Thank you.

Comment: If your real input contains more than 1 value in col1 then the example you provide for us to test with should have more than 1 value in col1. If you want help debugging the code you have then tell us what's wrong with the code you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written based on your shown samples. Tested it on https://ideone.com/MQBYuU

```
awk '
{
  a[$1]=a[$1]<$3?(a[$1]?a[$1]:$3):$3
  b[$1 OFS $3]=$0
}
END{
  for(j in a){
    print b[j OFS a[j]]
  }
}
' Input_file
```

Comment: @austin7923, edited my code and tested it successfully kindly check and do lemme know we should be good here. Lemme know how it goes.

Comment: @austin7923 `it doesn't work` is the worst possible problem description, it tells us absolutely nothing of any use to debug the problem.